# Efficient method of changing columns in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello I have an empty DatagridView that is disabled until I start adding rows to it. I have a combo box that has two selectable options that is going to control what information is going to get loaded into it and also vary the columns that are in there. Right now on the SelectionChanged event for the combo box I have something like:

```
if (defaultComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
   if (extractionDataGrid.Columns.Contains(companyIDColumn))
      {
         extractionDataGrid.Columns.Remove(companyIDColumn);
         extractionDataGrid.Columns.Remove(companyNameColumn);
         extractionDataGrid.Columns.Remove(maintenanceColumn);
         extractionDataGrid.Columns.Remove(simColumn);
      }

      extractionDataGrid.Columns.Add(userNameColumn);
      extractionDataGrid.Columns.Add(departmentColumn);
      extractionDataGrid.Columns.Add(officePhoneColumn);
      extractionDataGrid.Columns.Add(officePhontExtColumn);
      extractionDataGrid.Columns.Add(otherPhoneColumn);
. [18 columns]
.
.
.
```

And the opposite for a selected index of 1. There are quite a few columns here and was trying to think of a way to avoid huge blocks of code to initialize the new datagridview columns, adjust the header text, adjust the auto size mode, and various other parameters. Also when I switch back and forth between the selected index, this actually adds the columns in different orders every time. They should be added in the sequence I've set here??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add all your 0 index columns to a List
2. Add all your 1 index columns to another List
3. Pass the list of columns to a new method you create that iterates over the List to add or remove as necessary.
4. Put a synch lock on your add/remove methods. That is probably what is giving the appearance of different orders due to the

   extractionDataGrid.Columns.Remove(companyIDColumn);

i.e. the condition is met before the grid is fully updated.
Alternatively change the conditional so that it is independent of column order and so that it checks a variable that is only set after all the columns have been added and or removed.

i.e.

```
switch (gridMode){
  case GridMode.Company:
   this.AddColumns(userColumnList);
   gridMode = GridMode.User;
   break;
  case GridMode.User:
   this.AddColumns(userColumnList);
   gridMode = GridMode.Company;
   break;
}

protected void AddColumns(List<Column> adds){
  extractDataGrid.Layout.Suspend();
  extractionDataGrid.Columns.Clear();
  foreach(Column c in adds){
   extractionDataGrid.Columns.Add(c); 
  }
extractDataGrid.Layout.Resume();
}
```

Alternatively don't delete columns but rather turn off visibility if that's an option.